# simplexml_load_string not creating an object

Tags: php, simplexml

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <FindOrders xmlns="http://www.JOI.com/schemas/ViaSub.WMS/">
         <orders>
            <order>
               <MarkForName />
               <BatchOrderID />
               <CreationDate>2013-08-09T17:41:00</CreationDate>
               <EarliestShipDate />
               <ShipCancelDate />
               <PickupDate />
               <Carrier>USPS</Carrier>
               <BillingCode>Prepaid</BillingCode>
               <TotWeight>0.00</TotWeight>
               <TotCuFt>0.00</TotCuFt>
               <TotPackages>1.0000</TotPackages>
               <TotOrdQty>1.0000</TotOrdQty>
               <TotLines>1.00</TotLines>
               <Notes />
               <OverAllocated />
               <PickTicketPrintDate />
               <ProcessDate />
               <TrackingNumber />
               <LoadNumber />
               <BillOfLading />
               <MasterBillOfLading />
               <ASNSentDate />
               <ConfirmASNSentDate />
               <RememberRowInfo>398879:12:2:::0:False</RememberRowInfo>
            </order>
         </orders>
      </FindOrders>
      <totalOrders xmlns="http://www.JOI.com/schemas/ViaSub.WMS/">1</totalOrders>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When I do:

```
$a = simplexml_load_string($str);

print_r($a);
```

I get: `SimpleXMLElement Object ( )` instead of an object with all of those parameters. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the [namespace declaration (php manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php) for SOAP

```
$a = simplexml_load_string($str);
$a->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope');

$result = $a->xpath('//soap:Body');

print_r($result);
```

## Result ([preview](http://codepad.org/hbov7PEj#output))

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [FindOrders] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [orders] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [order] => SimpleXMLElement Object
  ...
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing when you say you want to see an object with all those parameters, you're looking to output the xml document you just created.

Looking at the documentation at http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php, here's what you need to do:

```
echo $a->asXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

My case was dealing with soap response. I have to parse and clean it first before converting it to array.

```php
$response = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $xml); // remove all colons and unnecessary characters.
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$body = $xml->xpath('//sBody'); // should refer to soap body element like soapbody, sbody, etc..
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)$body), TRUE);
```